# xpath relative path returns none

Tags: xpath, scrapy

When I place a dot to make my xpath relative, it return {"name":"none"}, when I remove the dot, it repeats the same data until the loop ends

```
.//*[@id="listingAds"]/section/section/ul/li[1]/a/section/h2
```

Here is the complete code

```
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/bretagne/']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.dontSwitch .trackable'
        for annonce in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):


            NAME_SELECTOR = './/*[@id="listingAds"]/section/section/ul/li[1]/a/section/h2'
            NAME_CATEGORIE = '.item_title+ .item_supp ::text'
            NAME_PLACE = '.item_supp+ .item_supp ::text'
            NAME_PRICE = '.item_price ::text'

            yield {
            'name': annonce.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `SET_SELECTOR` already gets you into the list of listings. In other words, each `annonce` selector corresponds to each search result element (each listing). Adjust your `NAME_SELECTOR` appropriately:

```
NAME_SELECTOR = './/h2/text()'
```